# Reverse accessor clashes in Django when adding custom user. Adding AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py doesn't work either

Tags: python, django

I got reverse accessor clashes error when trying to use a custom user model. I added AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py but still get the same error.

I am writing a Django project (Django version 2.2.2) when at a point I want to change to use the custom user model. There are already a couple of models, but it's fine to clear the database to start over at this stage, so I have deleted the sqlite3.db and all the migrations.

So to have a custom user model as per django documentation, I added:

in **`models.py`**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

... # other models
```

in **`settings.py`**:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'polls.User'
```

After that,

```
python .\manage.py makemigrations
```

should just work.
But it doesn't. It showed the same message as if I didn't add AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py at all:

```
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
polls.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
polls.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
```

No idea what could go wrong. Looks like most people around getting the same error is that they missed AUTH_USER_MODEL.

PS:
"polls" is my app name.

Tried change the custom user model's class name to something else for example "NovelUser" (replace the class name in models.py and AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py), still get the same type of error:

```
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'NovelUser.groups'.
```

etc.

PS: Don't think I have redefined any groups. I created a group in admin before I purged the database for this, but I have deleted splite3.db so I think that shouldn't matter.

PS: Defining AUTH_USER_MODEL simply seems to have no effect - if I comment out

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Then no errors would be found while the default user model would be used.

Comment: Are you redefining the Group model?

Comment: Try changing the model name to something like PollsUser, just in case it is not conflicting with the auth.User model class.

Comment: @Hagyn Yup tried, still auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'NovelUser.groups'. error.

Comment: @IainShelvington Don't think I have redefined any groups. I created a group in admin before I purged the database for this, but I have deleted splite3.db so I think that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was editing the wrong settings.py (I have a copy of settings.py under the 1st "mysite" which I couldn't recall how and why I added them in the first place. I know when thanks to git, but still totally puzzled at how and why I have done that at all even looking at that changelist).

The directory is like:

```
mysite
|- mysite
|  |- settings.py <- Should modify this one
|  |- ......
|  polls
|  |- (where most contents should be, including models.py etc)
|  |- ......
|- db.sqlite3
|- settings.py <- I had a copy of this file here and was modifying this file! Of course it won't work
```

OK, surely it's such a dumb mistake/question at the 1st place. However, based on the information I have given it is impossible for anyone than me to find out what's wrong, and also very difficult for me...